# Kineticjs image/shape/layer distortion

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-processing, kineticjs

I've been trying to achieve image distortion for a long time. After some search I found [this](http://www.buzzaka.com/deformation-dimage-avec-canvas/) one that was nice.

I'm trying to add this to a kineticjs project, I'm sure it's possible but I can't understand how to add it or how to implement it to my project. The image will do more than just distortion, it'll also do some filter color and brightness filter.

In the `main.js` [of this one](http://www.buzzaka.com/deformation-dimage-avec-canvas/) they started with getting the context of the whole canvas but I just want to do it for a node (actually an image or a layer).

Here is a jsfiddle who explain what I am trying to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/junkees/fab3w85k/1/ in this one I have a big issue, the grid don't move and for sur will never distort the image (jsfiddle deny cross domain ressources, that's why you can see a little epileptique effect when clicking on it or looking in the console).

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: OP's revised code works fine. The only problem is the cross-domain image. Putting the image on the same server will solve the problem. The following revised fiddle loads the image as data URL instead of loading it from another server. The code works without any other changes:

http://jsfiddle.net/fab3w85k/4/

---

I think you can achieve what you want using a custom shape. Then you can do your custom drawing in its "drawFunc" e.g. like this:

```
var customShape = new Kinetic.Shape({
    drawFunc: function(context) {
        //Do all the custom drawing for your  shape here. For example:
        //context.clearRect(0, 0, 100, 100);    
    }
});
```

Since you have the 2d context for the shape, you can do all your custom drawing however you like. "drawFunc" will be called whenever Kinetic wants to redraw the canvas. You can have Kinetic call this function by calling layer.draw() or stage.draw() functions.

Comment: i've done this: http://jsfiddle.net/junkees/fab3w85k/3/ it's perfectly what I whanted for the distortion but isn't using the kinetic.image because I can't see how to handle the returned image with kinetic to work on it (apply filter, rescal, and other things)

Comment: @YechouaGuedj, you are yet another victim of cross-domain image problem. Please note that due to security issues, browsers do not allow low level canvas manipulation of images unless CORS is properly set up. So your code is perfectly correct and working. All you need to do is host the image on the same domain that is serving the page and you will be good to go. Please see my edit for the fix.

Comment: I know that he work on a real server but I actually don't know how to reuse the distorted image (just apply a filter-color from kineticjs), I whant to convert the distorted image to a kinetic object (an image will be perfect) because the distortion is "just" a part of my application. actually the input file is an image and the output file is an distortedImage and I whant to set a kinetic.Image in the input and get a kinetic.Image on the output

Comment: You can use stage.toDataURL() for that purpose.

Comment: i'll try and make a jsfiddle: if it's work it'll be perfect for other who search for this feature and if it won't someone will tell me why (I hope)

Comment: I will be waiting to see the results! Looks like a nice thing.